# How to get the binary output of cargo run <rust.rs>?

Tags: rust, compilation, x86, binary, rust-cargo

When we compile a c file using gcc test.c -o test.
We can get the binary file as test.

But while running a file using cargo run test.rs in rust.
can we get the binary like we got in the C program?

**The original hello.c file:**

```
    void main() {
       // printf() displays the string inside quotation
       printf("Hello, World!");
       
    }
```

**The rust program:**

```
extern "C" {
    fn printf(_: *const libc::c_char, _: ...) -> libc::c_int;
}
unsafe fn main_0() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    printf(b"Hello, World!\x00" as *const u8 as *const libc::c_char);
}
pub fn main() { unsafe { main_0() } ::std::process::exit(0i32); }
```

**When using cargo it compiles and runs perfectly.**

```
└─$ cargo run hello.rs                    
   Compiling Rust_testing v0.1.0 (/home/pegasus/Documents/Rust_testing)
warning: crate `Rust_testing` should have a snake case name
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `rust_testing`

warning: `Rust_testing` (bin "Rust_testing") generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.17s
     Running `target/debug/Rust_testing hello.rs`
Hello, world!
```

**Here's my Cargo.toml file:**

```
[package]
name = "Rust_testing"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
```

I have a rust program named hello.rs.

The program is I'm unable to compile it using rustc. I generated the hello.rs using c2rust online transpiler. But if I use cargo run hello.rs the program runs smoothly.

while using rustc new.rs -o test,
I can get the x86 test binary.
How to get similar kind of file while using the cargo run new.rs?

I looked into the target/debug directory.
But there are so many directories and so many files there. How to know which on is created for which .rs file?

```
┌──(pegasus㉿pegasus)-[~/Documents/Rust_testing/target/debug]
└─$ ls
build  deps  examples  incremental  Rust_testing  Rust_testing.d
```

Comment: `gcc test.c -o test` isn't the compilation of a single file, it's both a compilation and a linking. Usually you build many `.o` files and then link them together as a single binary. That's what `cargo build` does as well; it compiles all dependencies, all `.rs` files and then links them all together as one binary. There isn't a *"one .rs file becomes one executable"* relationship.

Comment: I don't think you were actually ever running your `hello.rs` file. I think you did `cargo new Rust_testing` to create a new cargo project, and then did `cargo run` in it. The `Hello, world!` it printed was the default output of your generated `main.rs` file, not the one from your `hello.rs`.

Comment: True I noticed it now

Comment: You seem to be approaching things in an unusual way and it seems to be causing confusion. Why are you converting a simple C program to Rust instead of just creating/writing a new Rust program? What is your end goal?

Comment: It's part of my research. I need to compile the C programs. And convert the C to to rust. and compile the Rust too and compare both the binaries.

Comment: @ZeshanAhmedNobin Be aware that Rust debug code is very convoluted, though. So if you compile your C code with `-O3`, you also need to compile your Rust code with `cargo build --release` to give them a fair comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `cargo build`, you will find the binary in `target/debug/`. If you build in release via `cargo build --release`, you will find it in `target/release/`.

Be aware that `cargo run hello.rs` does **not** compile `hello.rs`. It will always compile `src/main.rs`. `hello.rs` will be passed to the compiled program as a command line argument.

> How to know which on is created for which .rs file?

There isn't one file for one `.rs` file. If your crate is a binary crate, then there will be exactly one executable with the name of your crate. In your case it's `Rust_testing`. You can run it with `./target/debug/Rust_testing`, or copy it somewhere else and execute it directly.

You **can** add multiple binaries per crate by putting them in the `src/bin` folder. For example, if you put your `hello.rs` file in `src/bin` and then execute `cargo build --all`, it will create a `target/debug/hello` executable that you can run.

For more information about `cargo`'s folder layout, read the [cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html).

If you are new to Rust, I highly recommend reading the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). It will guide you through how to use `rustup`, `rustc` and `cargo` step by step.

Comment: Here hello.rs is the file I wanna run

Comment: Then don't name it `hello.rs`. Name it `main.rs` and put it in `src/`. That's just how cargo works. For more information, read the [cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html).

Comment: @ZeshanAhmedNobin Added more information about compiling a `hello.rs` into a `hello` binary, maybe this is what you are looking for

Comment: I had put the diff hello.rs, new.rs in the src directory.
And then used the command cargo build --all in the Rust_testing dir.
And then checked the target/debug/ directory. It still shows the same files as before

Comment: @ZeshanAhmedNobin Don't put it in `src`. Put it in `src/bin`, as I said.

Comment: There's no src/bin.
Should I create a new bin dir in source? and put all of the rs files to it?

Comment: Yes, create a `src/bin` folder and put your `hello.rs` into it. It will then create a `target/debug/hello` executable. Please read the cargo documentation as mentioned, it is written in there.

Comment: You will notice that it worked when it doesn't print a newline after `Hello, World!`, because you forgot to add a `\n` in your `printf`. Also, the `W` in your `World` is capitalized, while it isn't in the Rust example.

Comment: Yes that worked. You are a life saver. I actually first used rust yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the community :)

Comment: @ZeshanAhmedNobin If you are new to Rust, I highly recommend looking at [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). It is very helpful.

Comment: @ZeshanAhmedNobin I completely agree with Herohtar. Most of what we discussed is in its first chapter already.